# Errors while running commands sudo apt-get update

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, update-manager

Here is a list of errors I am getting while running

```
$ sudo apt-get update
E: Failed to stat /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_InRelease - pkgAcqTransactionItem::TransactionState-stat (2: No such file or directory)
E: Failed to stat /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_main_binary-amd64_Packages - pkgAcqTransactionItem::TransactionState-stat (2: No such file or directory)
E: Failed to stat /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_main_binary-i386_Packages - pkgAcqTransactionItem::TransactionState-stat (2: No such file or directory)
E: Failed to stat /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_main_i18n_Translation-en - pkgAcqTransactionItem::TransactionState-stat (2: No such file or directory)
E: Failed to stat /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_main_dep11_Components-amd64.yml.gz - pkgAcqTransactionItem::TransactionState-stat (2: No such file or directory)
E: Failed to stat /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_main_dep11_icons-64x64.tar.gz - pkgAcqTransactionItem::TransactionState-stat (2: No such file or directory)
E: Failed to stat /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_restricted_binary-amd64_Packages - pkgAcqTransactionItem::TransactionState-stat (2: No such file or directory)
E: Failed to stat /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_restricted_binary-i386_Packages - pkgAcqTransactionItem::TransactionState-stat (2: No such file or directory)
E: Failed to stat /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_restricted_i18n_Translation-en - pkgAcqTransactionItem::TransactionState-stat (2: No such file or directory)
E: Failed to stat /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_restricted_dep11_Components-amd64.yml.gz - pkgAcqTransactionItem::TransactionState-stat (2: No such file or directory)
E: Failed to stat /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_universe_binary-amd64_Packages - pkgAcqTransactionItem::TransactionState-stat (2: No such file or directory)
E: Failed to stat /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_universe_binary-i386_Packages - pkgAcqTransactionItem::TransactionState-stat (2: No such file or directory)
E: Failed to stat /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_universe_i18n_Translation-en - pkgAcqTransactionItem::TransactionState-stat (2: No such file or directory)
E: Failed to stat /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_universe_dep11_Components-amd64.yml.gz - pkgAcqTransactionItem::TransactionState-stat (2: No such file or directory)
E: Failed to stat /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_universe_dep11_icons-64x64.tar.gz - pkgAcqTransactionItem::TransactionState-stat (2: No such file or directory)
E: Failed to stat /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_multiverse_binary-amd64_Packages - pkgAcqTransactionItem::TransactionState-stat (2: No such file or directory)
E: Failed to stat /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_multiverse_binary-i386_Packages - pkgAcqTransactionItem::TransactionState-stat (2: No such file or directory)
E: Failed to stat /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_multiverse_i18n_Translation-en - pkgAcqTransactionItem::TransactionState-stat (2: No such file or directory)
E: Failed to stat /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_multiverse_dep11_Components-amd64.yml.gz - pkgAcqTransactionItem::TransactionState-stat (2: No such file or directory)
E: Failed to stat /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_multiverse_dep11_icons-64x64.tar.gz - pkgAcqTransactionItem::TransactionState-stat (2: No such file or directory)
E: Failed to stat /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-backports_InRelease - pkgAcqTransactionItem::TransactionState-stat (2: No such file or directory)
E: Failed to stat /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-backports_main_binary-amd64_Packages - pkgAcqTransactionItem::TransactionState-stat (2: No such file or directory)
E: Failed to stat /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-backports_main_binary-i386_Packages - pkgAcqTransactionItem::TransactionState-stat (2: No such file or directory)
E: Failed to stat /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-backports_main_i18n_Translation-en - pkgAcqTransactionItem::TransactionState-stat (2: No such file or directory)
E: Failed to stat /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-backports_main_dep11_Components-amd64.yml.gz - pkgAcqTransactionItem::TransactionState-stat (2: No such file or directory)
E: Failed to stat /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-backports_main_dep11_icons-64x64.tar.gz - pkgAcqTransactionItem::TransactionState-stat (2: No such file or directory)
E: Failed to stat /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-backports_restricted_binary-amd64_Packages - pkgAcqTransactionItem::TransactionState-stat (2: No such file or directory)
E: Failed to stat /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-backports_restricted_binary-i386_Packages - pkgAcqTransactionItem::TransactionState-stat (2: No such file or directory)
E: Failed to stat /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-backports_restricted_i18n_Translation-en - pkgAcqTransactionItem::TransactionState-stat (2: No such file or directory)
E: Failed to stat /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-backports_restricted_dep11_Components-amd64.yml.gz - pkgAcqTransactionItem::TransactionState-stat (2: No such file or directory)
E: Failed to stat /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-backports_universe_binary-amd64_Packages - pkgAcqTransactionItem::TransactionState-stat (2: No such file or directory)
E: Failed to stat /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-backports_universe_binary-i386_Packages - pkgAcqTransactionItem::TransactionState-stat (2: No such file or directory)
E: Failed to stat /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-backports_universe_i18n_Translation-en - pkgAcqTransactionItem::TransactionState-stat (2: No such file or directory)
E: Failed to stat /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-backports_universe_dep11_Components-amd64.yml.gz - pkgAcqTransactionItem::TransactionState-stat (2: No such file or directory)
E: Failed to stat /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-backports_universe_dep11_icons-64x64.tar.gz - pkgAcqTransactionItem::TransactionState-stat (2: No such file or directory)
E: Failed to stat /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-backports_multiverse_binary-amd64_Packages - pkgAcqTransactionItem::TransactionState-stat (2: No such file or directory)
E: Failed to stat /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-backports_multiverse_i18n_Translation-en - pkgAcqTransactionItem::TransactionState-stat (2: No such file or directory)
E: Failed to stat /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-backports_multiverse_dep11_Components-amd64.yml.gz - pkgAcqTransactionItem::TransactionState-stat (2: No such file or directory)
E: Failed to stat /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-backports_multiverse_dep11_icons-64x64.tar.gz - pkgAcqTransactionItem::TransactionState-stat (2: No such file or directory)
E: Failed to stat /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-security_InRelease - pkgAcqTransactionItem::TransactionState-stat (2: No such file or directory)
E: Failed to stat /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-security_main_binary-amd64_Packages - pkgAcqTransactionItem::TransactionState-stat (2: No such file or directory)
E: Failed to stat /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-security_main_binary-i386_Packages - pkgAcqTransactionItem::TransactionState-stat (2: No such file or directory)
E: Failed to stat /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-security_main_i18n_Translation-en - pkgAcqTransactionItem::TransactionState-stat (2: No such file or directory)
E: Failed to stat /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-security_main_dep11_Components-amd64.yml.gz - pkgAcqTransactionItem::TransactionState-stat (2: No such file or directory)
E: Failed to stat /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-security_main_dep11_icons-64x64.tar.gz - pkgAcqTransactionItem::TransactionState-stat (2: No such file or directory)
E: Failed to stat /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-security_restricted_binary-amd64_Packages - pkgAcqTransactionItem::TransactionState-stat (2: No such file or directory)
E: Failed to stat /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-security_restricted_binary-i386_Packages - pkgAcqTransactionItem::TransactionState-stat (2: No such file or directory)
E: Failed to stat /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-security_restricted_i18n_Translation-en - pkgAcqTransactionItem::TransactionState-stat (2: No such file or directory)
E: Failed to stat /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-security_restricted_dep11_Components-amd64.yml.gz - pkgAcqTransactionItem::TransactionState-stat (2: No such file or directory)
E: Failed to stat /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-security_universe_binary-amd64_Packages - pkgAcqTransactionItem::TransactionState-stat (2: No such file or directory)
E: Failed to stat /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-security_universe_binary-i386_Packages - pkgAcqTransactionItem::TransactionState-stat (2: No such file or directory)
E: Failed to stat /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-security_universe_i18n_Translation-en - pkgAcqTransactionItem::TransactionState-stat (2: No such file or directory)
E: Failed to stat /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-security_universe_dep11_Components-amd64.yml.gz - pkgAcqTransactionItem::TransactionState-stat (2: No such file or directory)
E: Failed to stat /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-security_universe_dep11_icons-64x64.tar.gz - pkgAcqTransactionItem::TransactionState-stat (2: No such file or directory)
E: Failed to stat /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-security_multiverse_binary-amd64_Packages - pkgAcqTransactionItem::TransactionState-stat (2: No such file or directory)
E: Failed to stat /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-security_multiverse_binary-i386_Packages - pkgAcqTransactionItem::TransactionState-stat (2: No such file or directory)
E: Failed to stat /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-security_multiverse_i18n_Translation-en - pkgAcqTransactionItem::TransactionState-stat (2: No such file or directory)
E: Failed to stat /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-security_multiverse_dep11_Components-amd64.yml.gz - pkgAcqTransactionItem::TransactionState-stat (2: No such file or directory)
E: Failed to stat /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-security_multiverse_dep11_icons-64x64.tar.gz - pkgAcqTransactionItem::TransactionState-stat (2: No such file or directory)
```